# How can I make ListView work with ArrayAdapter in android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have been stacked for hours trying to solve that problem. I will explain my code structure.

I have two classes `TwitterActivity` (the main activity) and `SearchTwitter`. In`TwitterActivity` I sign in and then start the `SearchTwitter` activity. I have also their xml layout files, `activity_twitter.xml` and `search.xml`.

The classes look like:

```
public class TwitterActivity extends Activity 
{
    private Button mSignin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);

    mSignin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_id);
    mSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //startSiginingProcess(...)
                Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterActivity.this, SearchTwitter.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

The `activity_twitter.xml` has just a single button, Sign In button. The `SearchTwitter` activity looks like:

```
public class SearchTwitter extends ListActivity {
private Button buttonLogout;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    initializeComponent();
    initControl();

    /********************************************************/
    ArrayList<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
    events.add("Item1");
    events.add("Item2");

    ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.search, events));
    /********************************************************/
}

private void initControl() 
{
    //Finish Signing procces
}

private void initializeComponent(){
    buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
    buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
               //Just LogOut
     });
}
```

And `search.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#2175B0">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/logout" />

<ListView
     android:id = "@android:id/list"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLogout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**WHAT IS MY PROBLEM NOW**

- In the `SearchTwitter` activity I did extend `ListActivity`
- All I want to do is to make the code surrounded by stars in `SearchTwitter` work. I have tried lots of ways, but No result. My app always crashed.

I feel exhausted, I don't know what to do anymore. Feel free to ask any question. Any kind of help, suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.

PS: The code surrounded by stars is wrong.

**EDIT**

In the case `ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.search);` I get:

```
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): Process: com.bledi.android.twittertest, PID: 1861
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bledi.android.twittertest/com.bledi.android.twittertest.SearchTwitter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at com.bledi.android.twittertest.SearchTwitter.onCreate(SearchTwitter.java:38)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-22 04:14:39.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

**EDIT 2**

I changed `ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` to `ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);` and  `ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.search, events));` to `ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.search, android.R.id.text1 , events));` and I get somehow a non-crash app but the behavior is weird.

Comment: Please post logcat exception.

Comment: @GiruBhai I mentioned it above. This code Does not compile

Comment: As you said,app always crashed,Anyway what compilation error?

Comment: OK I will post the case where I set ` ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.search);`

Comment: The listView and adapter code looks legit. Must be something in code with stars

Comment: @Yosi199 yeah exactly, there is my problem.

Comment: Well without seeing the code and the exception you get when app crashes, we wont be able to do much help :)

Comment: @BlediBoss If you get compilation error then please post same also.

Comment: @GiruBhai how should this line be fixed: `ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` because like this it does not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define `listview` again in `Activity` when your Activity extends `ListActivity`.
Therefore remove this line

```
ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

And try to change

```
ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.search, events));
```

to

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,events));
```

where `simple_list_item_1` is  **Android internal layout view**

Comment: Ok but what about `ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` ?

Comment: ListView ls = getListView();

Comment: @BlediBoss Happy to help,enjoy coding.